# How to inject angular UI Bootstrap to angular module in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I want to inject the angular ui bootstrap into an angular module using typescript.

Here is my code :

```
 /// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts" />
angular.module("ReviewApp", ["ui.bootstrap" , angular.ui.bootstrap ]);
```

Im using libraries of [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the module is incorrect

Change

```
angular.module("ReviewApp", ["ui.bootstrap" , angular.ui.bootstrap ]);
```

To

```
angular.module("ReviewApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

And just make sure you have a script tag reference to ui.bootstrap in you markup.

Comment: i have added nuget package of angular ui bootstrap DefinitelyTyped although the .ts is added but there is no .js file for that file. how to get the js file ?

Comment: There should be a nuget package for the actual library if not you can get it from their github page directly and include that in your project.